# MongoDB: How to project single inner field of all documents in Java?

Tags: java, mongodb

Suppose I have collection of documents with structure below:

```
{
    "_id" : 1
    "name" : "user1",
    "age" : 25,
    "details": {
        "userType": 1
        ... many other fields here
    }
}
```

and I want to get all documents with fields "name" and "details.userType" only so I get result like this.

```
[
    {
        "name": "user1",
        "details": {
            "userType": 1
        }
    },
    {
        "name": "user2",
        "details": {
            "userType": 1
        }
    }
    ... etc
]
```

How can I achieve this using Java? I'm not sure how to project inner fields using java.

So far, I was able to project name field using this code

```
        Query query = new Query(Criteria.where("active").is(true));
        query.fields().include("_id").include("name");
        return template.find(query, BaseUser.class, collectionName);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have nested object, simplay you can use `.include("details.userType")`

Comment: i feel so stupid not trying it out in the first place. Thanks!